# Android Studio Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate memory

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, imagebutton

I am trying to create an app with a fragment that displays two ImageButtons. The images are loaded through xml with this kind of code:

```
<ImageButton
...
        android:id="@+id/image_button_lab"
        android:background="@drawable/lab"
.../>
```

and

```
<ImageButton
...
        android:id="@+id/image_button_wild"
        android:background="@drawable/wild"
.../>
```

The first one is a picture of a laboratory and the other one is a picture of a tiger. Both pictures are 1080 x 1080 square .jpeg images.

When I run the app and start this fragment, I get the following error (shortened:)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.example.umutberk.test,PID: 2959
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 41990412 byte allocation with 4194304 
free bytes and 22MB until OOM
```

I have tried adding;

```
dexOptions 
    {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

... to my android{...} segment in the build.gradle file.

Also tried increasing the VD RAM size to 4GB, creating a new VD with 4GB RAM allocation, also running the APK on my LG G4 and it crashes no matter what.

Looked at "Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently" tutorials within the official Android Studio documentation and the moethod there is not what I am trying to do. I am just trying to load images from "@drawable/" as the background of my ImageButtons. Any help would be appreciated!

(PS: It works when I change "@drawable/image" to "#ffffff" for the android:background. So I am sure it has to do with these two images.)

Also full error message here: http://pastebin.com/ZiegMfpB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't these particular allocations.  2 images of that size is semi-reasonable (semi because 2 pictures that big won't both fit on the screen at once, so why not load one at a time as needed).  The problem is that all of your allocations together are too much.  Look for leaks or memory you hold on to that doesn't need to be held-  especially bitmaps.  I'd use a heap dump to see if there's way too many of some object.

Also, increasing RAM to 4GB won't work-  the entire device doesn't have 4GB.  These are phones, not computers (hell computers didn't have that 4 years ago).

Comment: Hmm I see what you are saying, kinda. I tried loading one single image and it still is too much and the app crashes. I am not sure I know how to look for memory leaks and setting up a heap dump but I will look into it.